# Change background color of a table row on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my webpage, I have a table and I'd like to change the background of a row, and in the process, check the radio button corresponding to that row when the row is clicked. I tried the following using jquery :

```
<style>
  .active { background-color: #8fc3f7;}
</style>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $('#reqtablenew tr').click(function () 
       {
         $('#reqtablenew tr').removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
       });
  });
<script>
```

Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong or any workaround would be very welcome. I have included the following scripts in the page.
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> and src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"

Here's a fiddle of my table 
http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add `jquery`

Add this in you **css**

```
tr.active td {
   background-color: #8fc3f7;
}
```

I have updated your demo to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/7/)

**Updated** to check the `radio` try this,

```
$(this).find('[name="reqradio"]').prop('checked',true);
```

**Full Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reqtablenew tr').click(function () {
        $('#reqtablenew tr').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).find('[name="reqradio"]').prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/10/)

Comment: I edited the question. Could you also help me getting that radio button for the row checked on the click on row?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the td got background color too

```
.newreqtable td {
   .....
   background-color:#ffffff;
```

So you need to enforce your active class, e.g.

```
tr.active td{background-color: #8fc3f7;}
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/9/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ... :

```
$(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

.. will check the radiobutton of the clicked row.

[Fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/McNull/LwT9N/)